# C++ How can I make an element of an array of pointers to structs points to NULL?

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, null

I have a little problem with my homework for university. I have to use an array of pointers which all point to a struct.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct student {
       int matriculation;
       char *name:
       char *lectures[30];
};
```

Lectures should be an array of strings which I have to use (given in the task). It can save up to 30 lectures as strings. 
My array of pointers:

```
student people[1000];
student *pointer = &people[0];
```

To use such an array is also given in the task. It's like a register of students which can contains not more then 1000 students with their matriculation number, name and the lectures which they already have passed. When there are less then 1000 I have to point the empty elements to NULL. 
I tried like that:

```
pointer[i] = NULL;
```

The Var i is declared because I tried to point to NULL in a for-loop. The problem is that i get this `Error: no match for 'operator=' in '*(pointer + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 256ull))) = 0ll'`

How can I set the empty elements of the pointer-array to NULL?

Comment: You don't have an array of pointers. You just have an array of structs. If you want an array of pointers, that would be `student *people[1000]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your code

```
student people[1000];
```

To

```
student* people[1000];
```

And you're good to go

That way when you `pointer[i] = NULL;` then pointer[i] is a pointer to people struct and not a struct.